# Lua SSL certificate and Azure Iot hub

Tags: ssl, lua, tls1.2, nodemcu, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect my NodeMCU ESP-12N to Azure IoT hub.

I have created client with code like this:

```
esp8266 = mqtt.Client(DEVICE, 240, USER, PASSWD)
```

and receiving error on calling esp8266:connect

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (init.lua:127: ssl not
>   available)

When I previously have connect my Arduino, then it was important to flash Wi-Fi with SSL certificate. However I can't do it with NodeMCU (or more right to say - don't know how).

I can get certificates with:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ArduinoDemoHub.azure-devices.net:8883
```

When I have add (thank you @MarcelStör for hint, I have tried previously net.cert.verify)

```
tls.cert.verify([[
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGsTCCBJmgADJKJFdWgAIQF5Koy/50vI3cQAAAAhAXjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
......
lz3ZDUcyzRgG6TRtA3SjASEUlJMt3f7xuI2nNpt8p5gy9pXuRw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
]])

tls.cert.verify(true)
```

I'v received another error:

> Error Connecting: -5

**UPDATE**:
There is [another similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834637/trouble-connecting-nodemcu-to-microsoft-azure-iot-hub), and I have set time, but still without result.

**UPDATE 2**:
Here are some links that I trying to use:

[Use Azure IoT Hub without client libraries (MQTT)](https://maxwellweru.com/use-azure-iot-hub-without-client-libraries-mqtt/)

[Sending Device-to-Cloud (D2C) Messages](http://thinglabs.io/workshop/esp8266/sending-d2c-messages/)

[sankarcheppali gitHub with samples](https://github.com/sankarcheppali/NodeMCUProjects)

Here is official Link
[Communicate with your IoT hub using the MQTT protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support)
 that tells:

> To use the MQTT protocol directly, your client must connect over
>   TLS/SSL. Attempts to skip this will fail with connection errors.

This link also provides username that is different from old code samples:

```
{iothubhostname}/{device_id}/api-version=2016-11-14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created SAS with help of Device Explorer, that is looks like:

```
SharedAccessSignature sr={your hub name}.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FMyDevice01%2Fapi-version%3D2016-11-14&sig=vSgHBMUG.....Ntg%3d&se=1456481802
```

This value is set to PASSWD variable. Have changed USER variable to:

```
USER   = "MyAzureIoTHub.azure-devices.net/MyDeviceID/api-version=2016-11-14"
```

And has set to false tls.cert.verify

```
tls.cert.verify(false)
```

Works now :)

Answer (score 2):

TLS/SSL by default is **dis**abled in the firmware build configuration. [`CLIENT_SSL_ENABLE` in `user_config.h`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/include/user_config.h#L66) must be uncommented before compiling/building the firmware.

The easiest is to use the cloud builder at https://nodemcu-build.com (by yours truly) and check the TLS checkbox.

Also, all TLS/SSL related functions in the `net` module (you use `net.cert.verify`) were extracted into the `tls` module a while ago. Unless there's convincing arguments for **not** using a current firmware build I suggest you try the `dev` branch. When you enable "TLS/SSL support" in the builder you get the `tls` module automatically.

UPDATE: There is nice article about Azure IoT hub and certificates: [Certificate between IoT hub and devices connection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hanxia/2017/06/27/certificate-between-iot-hub-and-devices-connection/)

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly that service I have used. But seems something else also required.

Comment: Still no luck with dev. Keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following two libraries to connect NodeMCU ESP-12N to Azure IoT hub, these two libraries could be searched in Library Manager:

- **AzureIoTHubMQTTClient**
- **AzureIoTProtocol_MQTT** 
  [image]

After installation,you can refer to the samples.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Michael, it might be helpful for me. But I am trying use Lua, and still question stays how to add IoT hub SSL/TSL certificate. As I know connection should be secured.

Comment: You can set up secure transportation for MQTT Mosquitto broker with SSL/TLS.You can search the demo by googling "How to use Arduino ESP32 MQTTS with MQTTS Mosquitto broker (TLS/SSL)".

Comment: Thank you! This is more closer, but still not Lua

Comment: The OP is working with the NodeMCU firmware (Lua), not Arduino. This answer, albeit a good one, seems irrelevant in this context.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT, have you tried this "Thermostat" example yourself? As I see it doesn't using certificate. And even when I try it doesn't connect.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT "Thermostat" doesn't work, but simple_sample does.